# Execute a function inside ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to execute a function inside a ng-repeat to retrieve some other data to show.

For example I've a list of Apartments. I show this list using `ng:repeat`, than for each Apartment I would like to show the Owner, that is not the `u.Apartments`. So my `getInq` function make a call to a service to get the owner of a specified apartment. It seems to be logic for me, but it doesn't work.
It returns the **`"10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"`** error.

I've this code:

```
<div ng:repeat="u in units">
            <div ng:repeat="a in u.Apartments">
                <div class="targhetta" style="margin-top:10px">{{a.Name}}</div>
                <br />{{getInq(a.ApartmentId)}}
                <table>
                    <tr ng:repeat="cs in a.CS">
                        <td>{{cs.Position}}</td>
                        <td>{{cs.Code}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.getInq = function (idApp) {
            $http.get('http://localhost:8081/api/registry/GetLastInq?processdata=' + (new Date()).getTime() + '&appartamentoId=' + idApp, { headers: headers })
            .success(function (data2) {
                $scope.nomeInquilinoVw = data2.Name;
                $scope.cognomeInquilinoVw = data2.Surname;
                $scope.nomeCognome = $scope.nomeInquilinoVw + " " + $scope.cognomeInquilinoVw;
            })
            .error(function () {
                $scope.success = false;
                $scope.error = "There was an error!";
            });
            return $scope.nomeCognome;
        }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You should create a custom directive pass in any data you want from the ng-repeat and do any action you want. The directive will fire its link function on every ng-repeat loop

Comment: you can't have a http request as what's being returned as a function as it dosent exist when the function is called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a custom directive pass in any data you want from the ng-repeat and do any action you want. The directive will fire its link function on every ng-repeat loop

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  
  $scope.data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  
})
.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    template: '<div>{{ myDirective }}</div>', // where myDirective binds to scope.myDirective
    scope: {
      myDirective: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log('Do action with data', scope.myDirective);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in data" my-directive="item">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Check your console for the action

Comment: Thanks @Synapse. I've values in myDirective. How to show them in HTML? Or pass them to the controller $scope?

Comment: I've updated the example above to show you how to access inside the template the passed data

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `{{getInq(a.ApartmentId)}}` in your html. It will generate an awful lot of http request, that is why you are getting an error.

Instead call this function for every item you need from your controller, and add to the `$scope.units` variable to the correct place. This will end up just enough http request, and once you have them, will stop running more.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why this error happens is :

getInq return $scope.nomeCognome, and $scope.nomeCognome change every time when ng-repeat iterate the collection, every change will trigger the $digest cycle, which will cause a horrible result. you should avoid something like this will make $digest much complicated.

Answer (score 0):

angular directives are used to manipulate the 2 way data binding, you should not call the methods, as you have shown specially from within the two ng-repeat they are basically loops, It would slow down your page loading also. you should properly create your JSON for data binding within the controller. below should be you HTML code:

```
<div ng:repeat="u in units">
            <div ng:repeat="a in u.Apartments">
                <div class="targhetta" style="margin-top:10px">{{a.Name}}/div>

                <table>
                    <tr ng:repeat="cs in a.CS">
                        <td>{{cs.Position}}</td>
                        <td>{{cs.Code}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and in controller you should create your JSON  as

```
units=[
      { u.Appartment:[{a.cs[value1,value2]},{},{}]},{},{}]
```

something like this

```
for( var i=0; i<u.Apartment.length;i++)
{

  u.Apartment[i].cs=$scope.getInq(u.Apartment[i].Id);
}
```